# Strange DLP projector connection with RPI

Tags: usb, serial, connection

I am using nanodlp with a DLP light projector (wintech PRO6500) and a raspberry 4.

I have seen that the raspberry allows me to define /dev/ttyAMA0 referring to the projector. But /dev/ttyAMA0 already exists with the projector unplugged. Is it possible that that once the node is generated (when plugged in for first time) it remains present?

Also, it is strange, because with that address I can turn on and off the projector without getting any error, or at least the raspberry thinks I can do it, but no real result is happening. I mean if I have the light ON and I turn OFF the projector the light will not turn off.
For doing this I have to turn on the projector with the computer, and leave the light ON and then connect it to the raspberry, then I can control if I want to display an image or not with the raspberry, but it has no relation with the TURN ON or TURN OFF of the projector.

I have (* 0 IR 001) and (*0 IR 002) as commands to turn ON and OFF the display. Could it be that /dev/ttyAMA0 is the correct address but I have wrong codes?

I have tried controlling the projector with other addresses that are generated while connecting the projector, but I get the following error in the RPI software:

1. Error – Projector - USB port could not be activated is a directory if I use /dev/usb
2. Error – Projector - USB port could not be activated Invalid serial port if I use /dev/hidraw0

And I can choose between the following communication types, but none of them makes a better difference:

- Disabled
- USB / Serial Port – ASCII (\r\n)
- USB / Serial Port – ASCII (\r)
- USB / Serial Port – ASCII (\n)
- USB / Serial Port – Binary
- Execution Only

Do you think that /dev/ttyAMA0 can be the real address of the projector? I can only explain that if I have the wrong codes for turning ON and OFF the projector. And so the raspberry sees no error because is sending a command to the projector (correct address) and no result is occurring because of the wrong code.

If I do ‘dmesg’ in the raspberry I get this about the projector:

```
[    2.319611] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3 
[    2.322393] usb 1-1.1: Product: DLPC900 
[    2.325120] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: Texas Instruments Inc. 
[    2.327838] usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: C900 
[    2.347778] hid-generic 0003:0451:C900.0001: hiddev96,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Texas Instruments Inc. DLPC900] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.1/input0 
[    2.353106] usbhid 1-1.1:1.1: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
```

Here it seems that it is associated with /dev/hidraw0 and not /dev/ttyAMA0. But there is a final error.

What do you think about all this?

Comment: WITHOUT THE PROJECTOR:

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2341:0010 Arduino SA Mega 2560 (CDC ACM)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: WITH THE PROJECTOR:

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2341:0010 Arduino SA Mega 2560 (CDC ACM)
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0451:c900 Texas Instruments, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub