# Config.txt for connecting RPI4 to Light Projector

Tags: usb, serial, display, raspi-config, config.txt

I am using this code in the config.txt and I am not able to connect properly to the projector.
It is possible to decide to display or not an image but it isn't possible to turn On or Off the projector.

My problem is explained with more detail here:
[Strange DLP projector connection with RPI](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/119303/strange-dlp-projector-connection-with-rpi)

I attach my config and maybe someone sees an error.

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (force DMT 1920x1080 @60Hz)
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=82

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable the lirc-rpi module
#dtoverlay=lirc-rpi

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
disable_camera_led=1
hdmi_pixel_encoding=2
start_x=1
gpu_mem=128
enable_uart=1
```

Comment: No. That is my problem explained with another point of view. The question is mine too

Comment: Please do not duplicate questions.  If you have new info you can edit the question and just add into that.